# In Unison, is it possible to have smart constructors for unique types?

Tags: unison-lang

Take for example:

```
unique type ZeroOneClosed = ZeroOneClosed Float

> ZeroOneClosed 1.5
```

Here the idea is that we would have a function like `newZeroOneClosed: Float -> Either Float ZeroOneClosed` that takes any Float and only returns the right value if the float is in `[0,1]`, while at the same time, preventing us directly to call `ZeroOneClosed x` outside of some restricted scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the smart constructor, but restricting calls to `ZeroOneClosed` isn’t possible today, though it’s on the long-term roadmap.

For now, the closest you could get would be to use `delete.term` to remove the name of the constructor, which would make it a little harder (but not impossible) to call and a little harder to read as well, which you probably don’t want.